# Import script won't create files and folders on dedicated server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, plesk, mediatemple

I am using a script called `importbuddy.php` to restore a WordPress backup to my new dedicated virtual server.

**I think problem is, it creates folders as the `apache` user of the `apache` group.**  As a result, I can't seem to change permissions on the folders (even though I am logged in through Plesk as the `admin` user).  I am hosted on MediaTemple.net and I am using their (dv) Dedicated-Virtual server which uses Plesk.

This is an example of the errors that I am getting when I try to run the script:

> Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/controllers/ajax.php`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/css/style.css`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/bb-logo.png`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/bluebutton.jpg`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/bullet_error.png`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/bullet_go.png`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/button-grad.png`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/gray-grad.png`.
>   Error #65656. Unable to put file contents to
>   `/var/www/vhosts/internationalent.com/httpdocs/importbuddy/images/icon_16x16.png`.

How can I just make it so this importer will run and restore my WordPress site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the import script I just FTP'd the files.